# Restrict Userform responses to values in specific excel cells

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have created a VBA Userform in excel and am looking to restrict what can be input to the textbox labelled 'Date' to a list of dates listed in cells on another Sheet.

Is this possible? Or to populate a list box from specific cells?

Answer (score 1):

it's much better to use `ComboBox` or `ListBox` controls instead of a `TextBox` one

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    With MyUserForm '<--| change "MyUserForm" to your actual userform name
        .DatesCB.List = GetDates '<--| change "DatesCB" to your actual dates ComboBox name
        .Show
    End With

End Sub

Function GetDates()
    With Worksheets("Dates") '<--| reference "Dates" worksheet (change "Dates" to your actual dates worksheet name)
        GetDates = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value) '<--|change "A"'s to your actual column index with dates
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Or just set the RowSource property of the ListBox/ComboBox to the required range

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Rowsource property of a Comboboxs or Listboxs to a Range's external address will fill the control with the values of the range.  This will work for single or multi-column ranges.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ListBox1.RowSource = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Address(External:=True)

End Sub
```